# Django How to exclude field in a single modelForm for only updateview but not createview?

Tags: python-2.7, django-forms, django-class-based-views

i have a form class like UserForm

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
   email=forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','required': True}))
   password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','required': True}))

   class Meta:
       model=User
       fields=['email','password']
```

and 2 view CreateView and UpdateView.

```
class UserCreate(CreateView):
    template_name='admin/user_crud_form.html'
    form_class=UserForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('list_user')

class UserUpdate(UpdateView):
    template_name='admin/user_crud_form.html'
    form_class=UserForm
    exclude = ('password',)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('list_user')
```

right now i just need to exclude password field for edit. i only change the email every time. but not password** .

but on create user i will use both. how?? 
this code is not excluding password field in update view.
** I DONT WANT TO USE 2 FORMS FOR CREATE AND UPDATE **

thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe passsing `**kwargs` while creating the view can help!

Comment: can you provide an example it may help please :)

Comment: I am on mobile device, hence wouldnt be able to provide a good answer right away.
look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python) to understand `kwargs`

Comment: understood the concept of kwargs but dont get how to use in my scenario .. please provide an example according to my context if possible .. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the model form. So, you can override the method `__init__`.
Try below code

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(UserForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       attrs={'class':'form-control','required': True}
       if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
            self.fields.pop('password', None)
       for field in self.fields.values():
           field.widget.attrs = attrs

   class Meta:
       model=User
       fields=['email','password']
```

Comment: you are awesome... thanks a lot. @anujaneyulu-batta. you made my day.